# <ul>children serving as children not hovering over elements below

Tags: html, css

I've got a responsive horizontal bar above a vertical menu bar. The horizontal bar contains children  or dropdowns which seem to be pushing the vertical menu bar down rather than hovering above the vertical menu bar.

Its most likely something to do with my position attribute that I'm getting wrong but can't seem to identify where?

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong thanks.

[See my demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1240/)

HTML:

```
   <div class="horizontalmenubar">

        <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">HORIZONTAL MENU</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">MENU OPTION</a></li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">MENU OPTION</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">SUB-MENU OPTION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SUB-MENU OPTION</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">MENU OPTION</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">SUB-MENU OPTION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SUB-MENU OPTION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SUB-MENU OPTION</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">MENU OPTION</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">MENU OPTION</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="div_lhs_menu">

        <ul class="js-css-menu responsive vertical">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            <div>

              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </li>

          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            <div>

              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </li> <!-- class="current" for now not needed -->

          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        <div>

              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.horizontalmenubar {
    margin-top: 86px;
    background: #33DD00;
    width: 100%;
}

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
.horizontalmenubar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
.horizontalmenubar li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
.horizontalmenubar li a {
    display:block;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    background: #D6D6D6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
.horizontalmenubar li:hover a {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #3366ff;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
.horizontalmenubar li:hover ul a {
    background: #D6D6D6;
    color: #555;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
.horizontalmenubar li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #3366ff;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
.horizontalmenubar li ul {
    display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
.horizontalmenubar li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
.horizontalmenubar li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
.horizontalmenubar ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    background: #D6D6D6;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
.horizontalmenubar input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
.horizontalmenubar input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    .horizontalmenubar ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    .horizontalmenubar li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    .horizontalmenubar ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}

/* Main menu */
.js-css-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.js-css-menu, .js-css-menu ul, .js-css-menu li {
  list-style: none; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
}

.js-css-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.js-css-menu > li {
  display: inline-block; 
  float: left;
}

.js-css-menu > li > a {
  color: #555; 
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  background: #D6D6D6;
}

.js-css-menu > li:hover > a {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #3366ff;
}

/* Dropdown */
.js-css-menu > li div {
  position: absolute; 
  display: none;
  background: #D6D6D6;
}

.js-css-menu > li:hover div {
  display: block;
}

.js-css-menu > li div ul {
  float: none;
}

.js-css-menu > li div ul li {
  padding: 15px 15px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  font-weight: normal; 
}

.js-css-menu > li div ul li:hover {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #3366ff;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/* Vertical */
.js-css-menu.vertical {
  width: 200px; /* Adjust the width of the vertical menu */
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li {
  display: block; 
  float: none; 
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div {
  width: 150px; 
  top: 0;
  left: 201px; /* Adjust the left value according to the width of the vertical menu */
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div ul li:hover {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #3366ff;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div ul li a {
    color: #555;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div ul li a:hover {
    color: #3366ff;
}

.js-css-menu.firstitem {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: What is it you exactly want it to look like?

Comment: @papakia I think he wants the menus on the left to be always at the top, touching the upper menu bar so to say. When the submenus of the upper bar show up the left menu gets pushed downwards.

Comment: @xufox: u got it spot on .. i want to stop the dropdowns from the horizontal menu bar pushing down vertical bar

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to set **z-index** to the container divS (first u have to close the second one :) ) So **"z-index: 2 or grater"** on the first (the horizontal) and **"z-index: 1 or less than the first one"**, now your horizontal bar shuld appear above the vertical one. Next step is more **important**, you have to set **"position: relative"** on the first div-container and **"position: (absolute or fixed and NOT static)"** on the second div-container, I did it with position: absolute and fixed with **top: 124px** to place the vert-bar on his place but those px-s depends on your further layout. Remember z-index only applies to elements that have been given an explicit position.
So changes in CSS are:

```
.horizontalmenubar {
z-index: 333;
position: relative;
}
#div_lhs_menu {
position: absolute;
top: 124px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... Does this mean all elements below my vertical menu bar e.g. footer bar need a fixed top value .. For example in this demo (http://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1244/) the dropdowns are pushing down on the footer .. I havent set a top value for the footer ..

Answer (score 0):

When I resised smoothly the window the menu options were placed over the vert-bar until the green bar appeared (this is somthing you should think of).

All depends on your idea and layout.
**1.** First idea is to continue fixing the independent elements e.g. footer bar etc, but hard fixing a lot of elements can brake the design soon or later, despite the fact that this was my idea in the beggining I think it is bad practice and u shouldnt do it. :)
**2.** Second idea is to wrapp the vert-bar and the footer in **wrapper div**(or other block element) and give him the **fixing** and the **z-index**:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="div_lhs_menu"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>

.wrapper {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 124px;
}
```

Now you have the horizontal bar over the vertical bar + the footer, but dropdown is covering some area of the footer verry naughty :)

Tell me if you want to make the footer appear after the dropdown when green bar is triggered.

And maybe overflowing the vert bar shuld be only when that green bar is visible, if this is your goal consider making all the positioning and z-ndexing with @media queryz.
Best reagards!

Comment: really appreciate the help .. I've attempted wrapping the vertical bar and footer bits together .. here's the demo (http://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1252/) ... and its behaving more or less the same way ...

Comment: Small difference indeed. BTW last fidlle (1252) I didnt saw the horizontal bar. Maybe I didn't understood the problem properly, so if you could tell me what is your goal again, maybe i could repair myself :)